# Create sheets based in a list of name and copy values to this sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I´m really stuck with this.

I have a google spreadsheet, in the first sheet I have two columns A and B.

In the A column there are the names of wallpaper collections and in B the URLs of these collections.

I have a second sheet which is a template. What I want is to copy the template and rename it with the names of the wallpaper collections and in each copy with different name have the correlative URL in the cell A2.

I was able to create the sheets based in a names present in the column A, but this copy is a blank sheet, I don't have any clue how I select the template to be copied and renamed with the names of the collections, and in each sheet copy the correlative URL in the cell A2.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add `Google-apps-script` tag

Comment: Perhaps this might help`insertSheet(sheetName, sheetIndex, options) Sheet Inserts a new sheet in the spreadsheet with the given name at the given index and uses optional advanced arguments.` or perhaps this `insertSheet(sheetName, options) Sheet Inserts a new sheet in the spreadsheet with the given name and uses optional advanced arguments.` [Learn more here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet).